# nltk: word_tokenize changes quotes

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I'm using Python's nltk and I want to tokenize a sentence containing quotes,  but it turns `"` into ``` `` ``` and `''`.

E.g:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize

>>> sentence = 'He said "hey Bill!"'
>>> word_tokenize(sentence)
['He', 'said', '``', 'hey', 'Bill', '!', "''"]
```

Why doesn't it keep the quotes like in the original sentence and how can this be solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually meant to do that, not on accident. From [Penn Treebank Tokenization](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/tokenization.html)

> double quotes (") are changed to doubled single forward- and backward- quotes (`` and '')

In previous version it didn't do that, but it was updated last year. In other words if you want to change you'll need to edit `treebank.py`

Comment: That's pretty unintuitive. The link is broken to read more about it :(

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the answer provided by Leb:

The URL for Penn Treebank Tokenization is no more available. But its present in ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/treebank/public_html/tokenization.html

Copy-pasting the content here:

> **Treebank tokenization**
>
> ```
>     Our tokenization is fairly simple:
> ```
>
> - most punctuation is split from adjoining words
> - double quotes (") are changed to doubled single forward- and backward- quotes (`` and '')
> - verb contractions and the Anglo-Saxon genitive of nouns are split into their component morphemes, and each morpheme is tagged
>   separately.
>
>   ```
>   Examples
>        children's --> children 's
>        parents' --> parents '
>        won't --> wo n't
>        gonna --> gon na
>        I'm --> I 'm
>   ```
>
>   This tokenization allows us to analyze each component separately, so (for example) "I" can be in the subject Noun Phrase while "'m" is
>   the head of the main verb phrase.
> - There are some subtleties for hyphens vs. dashes, elipsis dots (...) and so on, but these often depend on the particular corpus or
>   application of the tagged data.
> - In parsed corpora, bracket-like characters are converted to special 3-letter sequences, to avoid confusion with parse brackets. Some POS
>   taggers, such as Adwait Ratnaparkhi's MXPOST, require this form for
>   their input.
>   In other words, these tokens in POS files: ( ) [ ] { }
>   become, in parsed files: -LRB- -RRB- -RSB- -RSB- -LCB- -RCB-
>   (The acronyms stand for (Left|Right) (Round|Square|Curly) Bracket.)
>
>   Here is a simple sed script that does a decent enough job on most corpora, once the corpus has been formatted into
>   one-sentence-per-line.

Example from Stanford:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml

**Command-line usage** section shows example of how double quotes are changed as per the rules of Penn Treebank tokenization.

https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/treebank.html

**class TreebankWordTokenizer** shows how the changes have been implemented:

```
# starting quotes
 (re.compile(r"^\""), r"``")

# ending quotes
(re.compile(r'"'), " '' ")
```